# In my code my variables from another file are not updating when I change them

Tags: python, file, import

I am having trouble with a few variables in my text adventure. in one file I have all my variables, but when I update them in one file, it doesn't change them in another file. I am using from var import * but that is keeping them at the original value. check out my code please. I am open to suggestions.

my code: https://replit.com/@BryanMurphy4/EvilMarvelousSpool#town2.py

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Firstly `from var import *` doesn't work the way you think it does. Secondly try to avoid this import pattern at all costs. Thirdly what you meant was: `import var` and then you can do things like `var.m -= 10` to update `m` instead of `m=m-10`.

Comment: Put your code inside the site instead of the link